# For loop complexity analysis representation

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, time-complexity

Okay so look at the **for loop**:

```
public long plants(long a, long b) {
    long r = 0;
    if (a==0) {
        r = b;
    } else {
        a = a-1;
        b = b-1;
        for (int i=1; i<a; i*=2) {
            r++;
        }
        r = plants(a, b)
        r = r * (a + b);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Here the size of the problem is `a`, so `n = a`.

In the solution, the representation for the loop is:
[https://i.gyazo.com/67cc2154a93a208475b83004eb60a457.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kCzj.png)

[image: \sum_{x=1*2^{i}}^{n}k1+k2]

Can someone explains me what's "**k1 + k2**"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the sum of two values, the exact meaning of which may be explained in context that you haven't provided. There is no apparent relation between this formula and the code.

Comment: By the way, the `for` loop in your code is completely pointless because the value of `r` is later overwritten.

Comment: Oh, two constants, so useful answer...

Comment: interjay, there's no context. It's a complexity exercise. They give me that algorithm and they ask me for the T(n) of the recursive "plants(a,b)". It's T(n) = T(n-1) + Top, where Top is the T(n) of the rest of code, in this case, the loop. In the solution of loop, they give that summation and then the T(n), but I don't understand why there are two constants, k1 and k2 (there's only "r++" inside the loop).